# Is it possible to add a library path to an init script?

Tags: shared-libraries, redhat, ld

We have an application that runs as a service daemon on a RedHat system.

For now, the RPM we have to install this package creates a soft link from our application's library folder into /usr/lib64, and the daemon recognises that.

I would like to be able to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the init script (/etc/init.d/myscript) so that we don't need to create that soft link (therefore, if multiple applications that use different versions of the library are installed, they will use what is in their own installation folder, and also we won't mess with the standard lib folders).

Is this possible? I tried a simple `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/myapp/lib:/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but that did not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Try next in your init script:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/myapp/lib:/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: is this a trial you are asking OP to do? or Is it a tested answer?

Comment: It is tested by myself, sorry that my question led to misunderstanding. It should be formatted in positive. thanks